# Find extreme directions of $S=\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n:x_1 \ge x_2 \ge ... \ge x_n \ge 0\}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the set $S=\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n:x_1 \ge x_2 \ge ... \ge x_n \ge 0\}$.

Find its extreme directions.

---

By definition the zero vector $\mathbf d \ne \mathbf 0$ is an extreme direction of $ \emptyset \ne S \in \mathbb R^n$ if for $\mu_1,\mu_2 >0$ and regression directions $\mathbf d_1,\mathbf d_2$ of $S$ : $$\mathbf d =\mu_1 \mathbf d_1+\mu_2 \mathbf d_2$$ then either $\mathbf d=\alpha \mathbf d_1$ or $\mathbf d=\beta\mathbf d_1$ for some $\alpha,\beta>0 $

Although I don't know how to apply this definition to find the extreme directions of $S$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Write $x_i = y_1 + \cdots + y_i$, where $y_1$, $\ldots$, $y_n \ge 0$. Reduce to finding the extreme directions of another cone.

Comment: I generally don't know how to find extreme directions of a given set, and in this case I don't know how to use your hint